# Git pull setup to update the submodule to the checkout SHA of remote

Tags: git, git-submodules, pull

I'm trying to setup git to execute the `git submodule update --init --recursive` on all git pull command (or when there is a new commit being pulled on the server side).

My goal is to have my colleague and me not being bitten in the a** again by someone doing a `git add *` or `git pull` and then having to manually play with the submodule commands to revert his issue.

My problem is that I believe that cloning a project and/or pulling should be updating with the configuration of the remote git (this include the submodule).  The situation occurred a lot with the high-level project where libraries were developed but people forgot to update their submodules...

I though this would have been answered by now, but I can't find it.  Now, I have colleague that want a single git repo (no submodule) but that bring it's own sets of problems for CI/CD point of view...

I don't want to have to do something like Piper (Google solution) to manage this...  I believe someone must have the answer and could help me figure it out.

Regards,
Eric Lafontaine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I leave this answer in reference.For solving the problem of updating the submodule on a pull, we need to understand how git submodule works.

Submodule are a nesting of a git repo in another git repo.  In other words, the first Git (project) reference to another Git repo (the submodule, could be a library).  When working with a standard submodule, it will be checked out as a detached Head with a specific SHA.  This means that doing a pull on it will ***not*** update the project reference.

If the submodule is configured to follow a branch, than that would means that we expect the submodule to evolve and we also expect it to always conform to some standard to our project.

With this in mind, when we do a `git pull` we would like the submodule to be "checked out" to the revision we've configured (whether it be a specific commit or a branch).  To do this, we can configure the "fetch" to be recursive on our config ;

`git config --global fetch.recurseSubmodules true`

I expect that being configured that way, you want to work with git submodules.  Then this trick might be useful to see conflict in the submodule before doing a push;

`git config --global push.recurseSubmodules check`

ref:[https://chrisjean.com/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/]